# Qt C++ How to chop a letter of QString that is member of a QStringList in 1 command

Tags: c++, qt, qstring, chop, qstringlist

in my code I need to remove the last space(s) of a QString that is an element of a QStringlist DataColumns.

This is what I have:

```
  DataColumns[0] : "Time [ms]      "
  DataColumns[1] : "Position [m]"
  DataColumns[2] : "End Velocity [m/s]     "
```

This is what I want to have:

```
  DataColumns[0] : "Time [ms]"
  DataColumns[1] : "Position [m]"
  DataColumns[2] : "End Velocity [m/s]"
```

In a loop over i (element of DataColumn) and j (letter of element of DataColumn) I do the following and it works:

```
 QStringList dataColums;
 QString A;
 ...
 A= dataColums[i];
 A.chop(1);
 dataColums[i] = A;
```

But when I try to put the last 3 lines into 1 command it doesn`t work.

```
dataColums[i] = dataColums[i].chop(1);
```

Can anybody explain to my as to why that is? Thank you!

Comment: The operator `[]` returns a reference of the `QString`, so why don't you just do: `dataColumns[i].chop(n)` ? But yes, QString::trimmed() would be much better for your case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function is declared like

```
void QString::chop(int n);
```

that is it has the return type `void`.

So this statement

```
dataColums[i] = dataColums[i].chop(1);
```

is invalid. It looks like

```
dataColums[i] = void;
```

To remove white spaces from the both sides of a string you could use the member function `trimmed`.

Answer (score 2):

If you just need to remove spaces you can use the [QString::trimmed](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstring.html#trimmed) function!

Alternatively, you can remove all the characters after the last `]` using [QString::truncate](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstring.html#truncate) combined with [QString::lastIndexOf](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstring.html#lastIndexOf).